# Why won't my foreach work?

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

```
$subSpecialties = $this->_db->get('users_subspecialties',array('user_id', '=', $this->_data->id));

print_r($subSpecialties);

foreach ($subSpecialties as $subSpecialty) {
    echo "THIS CODE IS GENERATED FROM INSIDE FOREACH";
}
```

The first line gets records from my `users_subspecialties` table

I then used `print_r` to check the records found.

The output is shown below:

```
DB Object ( [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object ( ) [_query:DB:private] 
=> PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM 
users_subspecialties WHERE user_id = ? ) [_error:DB:private] => 
[_results:DB:private] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] 
=> 1 [subspecialty_id] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 
[subspecialty_id] => 3 ) ) [_count:DB:private] => 2 )
```

Last line is my `for-each`; it should run because there are 2 records found as you can see with the `print_r` output and yet it won't `echo` the code inside.

Can someone tell me what seems to be the problem, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: inside loop print_r($subSpecialty); use this....and check the response

Comment: You need to foreach on the results, not the database object.

Comment: Try `foreach ($subSpecialties->results() as $subSpecialty)`.

Comment: Btw, where did you get that DB class from? Is it PEAR or something?

Comment: No Jack, I followed phpacademy tutorial on youtube it was very handy.
Can I download classes online? I haven't tried one. It would be great if you can point out if there are great ones I can download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$subSpecialties = $this->_db->get('users_subspecialties',array('user_id', '=', $this->_data->id));

print_r($subSpecialties);

foreach ($subSpecialties->results() as $subSpecialty) {
    echo "THIS CODE IS GENERATED FROM INSIDE FOREACH";
}
```

Comment: Silly me :)
I was missing ->results()
Thanks for the help
I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

if this response is object you get like this:

```
foreach ($subSpecialties as $subSpecialty) {
   echo $subSpecialty->user_id;
   echo '<br/>';
   echo $subSpecialty->subspecialty_id;
}
```

if this response is array then

```
foreach ($subSpecialties as $subSpecialty) {
   echo $subSpecialty[user_id];
   echo '<br/>';
   echo $subSpecialty[subspecialty_id];
}
```